# TestNG Report customization

Tags: java, testng

My TestNG report shows result of both tests   SuperPrizeSweep1 & SuperPrizeSweep1_complete. I need to show result of just one test SuperPrizeSweep1 in TestNG report, is there a way i can do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >  
    <suite name="Main Suite" parallel="false">

       <test name="Android Automation" preserve-order="true">
            <classes>
               <class name="com.TestSuite.TestSet3"> 
                <methods> 
                    <include name="SuperPrizeSweep1" />
                    <include name="SuperPrizeSweep1_complete" />                                                          
                </methods>              
               </class>
            </classes>
    </test>                                          
 </suite>
```

Comment: share your com.testng.report.custom.CustomTestNGReporter code

Comment: Sorry i am not implementing CustomTestNGReporter.

Comment: ok. Then in which report you want to show that SuperPrizeSweep1 test? xml report?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get this done without building your own `IReporter` listener implementation which you would wire in as a TestNG listener.

TestNG's default reports by default show all tests that were executed (so you would see this in both the `emailable-report` and also the `html report` that TestNG by default provides as of today.

If you would like to build this you could do it as below

- Create a new custom marker annotation say `IgnoreFromReport` which you would need to add to all methods that you would like to be excluded from the report.
- Implement `org.testng.IReporter` interface wherein for all the `ITestResult` objects that you have in your suite (`ITestResult` object is one per `@Test` method), you would extract out the corresponding `java.lang.reflect.Method` object (Which represents the actual test method) and check if it has the afore-mentioned marker annotation and if yes, exclude it from the reports.